# Reading GNU radio binary file using Matlab for postprocessing

Tags: matlab, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have saved a gnu radio binary file of my experiment, which I would like to open on Matlab for further post-processing. However, the normal fopen,fread doesn't seem to work as the array it generates contains only zeros, which contradicts the output seen on gnu radio when the file is used as a file source. Moreover, I have tried using read_complex_binary() function for gnu radio on Matlab which produces the same array like the one above mentioned. Please see the attached image.

My goal: open the gnu file on Matlab so that I get the same plot as figure 2

Comment: There's an [FAQ entry](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_the_file_format_of_a_file_sink.3F_How_can_I_read_files_produced_by_a_file_sink.3F) for that.

Comment: I referred to the FAQ entry in gnuradio with Matlab, but the said method did not work for me to convert the data into complex values. 

Instead of `complex_v = values(1,:) + values(2,:)*i;`, 
try `complex_v = values(1:2:end) + values(2:2:end)*1i;`

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` should work, maybe you have problem with encoding. Try this to force Big-Endian:

```
f = fopen(filename, 'rb'); 
v = fread(f,count); 
fclose(f);
```

But remember that MATLAB by default would treat data as integer. If there are different type (you didn't specified it in question) you need to declare it, for example `v = fread (f, count, 'float')`.